# Invoke aciton method with input value as parameter

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have this view:

```
<h:form id="carlin">
    <h:outputText id="carlinInput" value="#{userBean.model.varAjax}"/>
    <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>
</h:form>
```

And I have a modal dialog that shows another form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.model.varAjax}"/>
    <h:commandLink action="#{userBean.processPage1()}" value="Ok">
        <f:ajax render=":carlin:carlinInput" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

I need to set the value typed on the `<h:inputText>` and pass it as a parameter to my `<h:commandLink action="#{userBean.processPage1()}"` value="OK">`

Here is my `processPage1()` method:

```
public void processPage1(String zip) {
    this.model.varAjax = zip;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{userBean.processPage1(userBean.model.varAjax)}" value="OK">
```

But it doesn't work. If I pass a hardcoded value, it works:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{userBean.processPage1('teste')}" value="OK">
```

But I need to pass what the user typed on that `inputText` to my action method. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right approach. You need to specify the client IDs of the input components which you need to process/execute by the `execute` attribute of `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="varAjax" value="#{userBean.model.varAjax}"/>
    <h:commandLink action="#{userBean.processPage1}" value="Ok">
        <f:ajax execute="varAjax" render=":carlin:carlinInput" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

This way JSF will set the model value with the submitted value.

```
public void processPage1() {
    System.out.println(model.getVarAjax()); // Look, JSF has already set it.
}
```

An alternative is to use `execute="@form"` which will process the *entire* form and this is what you usually need in standard ajaxified buttons.

```
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":carlin:carlinInput" />
```

Note that componenent libraries like PrimeFaces and RichFaces have already made the `@form` the default execute attribute, so you don't need to explicitly specify it in their command components. In standard `<f:ajax>` it namely defaults to `@this` in command components which is indeed unintuitive.

Comment: so just on `execute` and things work...I've spent 1 hour looking for this. Thank you BalusC

Comment: You're welcome. For other useful hints, see also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html